# TranslateZ doesn't work with Framer motion motion component

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transforms, framer-motion

What should I do to place animated elements at different distances from the main card?

```
        <motion.div
          className={styles.homepage}
          style={{ x, y, rotateX, rotateY, **z: 100** }}
          drag
          dragElastic={0.16}
          dragConstraints={{ top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
          whileTap={{ cursor: "grabbing" }}
        >
          <div className={styles.iconsContainer}>
            <motion.img
              style={{ x, y, rotateX, rotateY, **z: 1000**  }}
              className={`${styles.iconImg} ${styles.css}`}
              src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/img/homePage/css.svg"}
              alt="css"
              draggable="false"
            />
            <motion.img
              style={{ x, y, rotateX, rotateY, **z: 500**  }}
              className={`${styles.iconImg} ${styles.html}`}
              src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/img/homePage/html.svg"}
              alt="css"
              draggable="false"
            />
          </div>
        </motion.div>
```

I tried to use z with different px, like 500px and 1000px. But translateZ doesn't react at  all.

Comment: It moves elements in the Z axis. The projection is by default orthographic so further elements are the same size as close ones